# how to filter data from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have create several indexes in an elasticsearch. The result of the `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v` indicate as follows.

```
health status index                                        pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow open   idx_post:user:5881bc8eb46a870d958d007a         5   1          6            0     31.3kb         31.3kb 
yellow open   idx_usr                                        5   1          2            0     14.8kb         14.8kb 
yellow open   idx_post:group:587dc2b57a8bee13bdab6592        5   1          1            0      6.1kb          6.1kb
```

I am new to elasticsearch and I tried to filter data by using the index `idx_usr`.

```
http://localhost:9200/idx_usr/_search?pretty=1
```

it is working fine and it returns the expected values. But when I am trying to  grab data by using the index `idx_post` it returns an Error saying the index is not found.

```
http://localhost:9200/idx_post/_search?pretty=1
```

This gives the result:

```
{
  "error" : "IndexMissingException[[idx_post] missing]",
  "status" : 404
}
```

If anyone can identify the reason. I would be really thankful.

**Update::**

This is how do I create the index. Assume that there is an object call data. And I am using an ES client call `this.esClient`

```
    var _esData = {
        index: "idx_post:group"+data.group_id;
        type:'posts',
        id:data.post_id.toString() 
    };

    _esData['body'] = data;
    this.esClient.index(_esData, function (error, response) {
        if(error)
            console.log(error);
        callBack(response);
    });
```

Comment: Can you show how you indexed your data, because it looks like your index is called `idx_post:group:587dc2b57a8bee13bdab6592` and not simply ìdx_post`, i.e. you mixed the index name, the mapping type and the document id in your index name.

Comment: @Val I have update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because index does not exists

```
{
  "error" : "IndexMissingException[[idx_post] missing]",
  "status" : 404
}
```

You try to search in `idx_post` while **_cat** returns name `idx_post:user:5881bc8eb46a870d958d007a` and `idx_post:group:587dc2b57a8bee13bdab6592`

Comment: Did you mean `idx_post:user:` or `idx_post:group:` is the index ?

Comment: I mean that index name is what is highlighted. With numbers and lettere

Comment: Clear. Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the results you want by querying your indexes like this with a wildcard

```
http://localhost:9200/idx_post*/_search?pretty=1
                              ^
                              |
                           add this
```

Comment: This answer is really helpful. Thank you for commenting.